# Limit distribution is invariant

Tags: probability, measure-theory, markov-chains

Consider a homogeneous Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with a countable (but not necessarily finite) state space $S$. Suppose that there exists a limit distribution $\pi$, namely:
$$\pi(j)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=j)\qquad\forall j\in S$$
I want to prove that $\pi$ is an invariant distrubution, that is the following equation must be satisfied:

$$\pi(j)=\sum_{i\in S}\pi(i)P_{ij}\quad\textrm{where}\quad P_{ij}:=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$$

The following proof of the above statement has a mysterious passage for me:

$$\pi(j)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=j)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i\in S}P(X_n=i)P_{ij}=$$
$$=\sum_{i\in S}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=i)\right)P_{ij}=\sum_{i\in S}\pi(i)P_{ij}$$

I don't understand why it is possible to exchange the limit and the summation! I some books I read "thanks to dominated convergence theorem" but I can't realize how to apply this result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(X_n=i) = \pi(i)$ and that $\sup_n P(X_n = i)P_{ij} = \sup_n |P(X_n = i) P_{ij}| \leq P_{ij}$. This means that you use the dominating function $i \mapsto P_{ij}$ noting that $\sum_i P_{ij} = 1$ (hence $i \mapsto P_{ij}$ is in $L^1$) and apply the DCT. Does this clarify the use of the DCT?

Comment: I don't se the integral. Maybe it is a stupid observation.

Comment: A sum is an integral with respect to the counting measure. If you're not comfortable with measure theory to the point of familiarity with counting measures, I found the following set of notes online that build up the theory with series: https://www.math.hmc.edu/~krieger/analysisresults.pdf